# Excel IF functions and equations

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a problem in excel, I want to make mathematical equation, ive tried it and I have problem with that function, it gives me error. I want have result in G6 if i type W in F6, then it will type in G6 : E6 if i type L in F6, then it will type in G6 : -D6 i think that I can get -D6 by multiplying D6 with -1

[image: Image of Formula]

by the way : KDYŽ means IF  in my language

Comment: I think you want commas (`,`) rather than semi-colons (`;`) to separate your arguments to IF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you need to nest your IFs) (I also incorporated @ScottHunter answer on string literals):

In English:

```
=If(F6="L", D6*-1, If(F6="W", E6, ""))
```

In your language:

```
=KDYŽ(F6="L"; D6*-1; KDYŽ(F6="W"; E6; ""))
```

The above works for me as shown here:

[image]

Comment: it doesnt do anything

Comment: @RostislavDanko Try it with `;` instead of `,` if that is what your language uses.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your string literals (i.e. F6="L").